# Working on Small Resolution Images in Photoshop ( icons )

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, icon, resolution, favicon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to resize icon sets in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5269/how-to-resize-icon-sets-in-photoshop)

I want to get a solution for a question that has been in my mind for a long time.

For the past 2 years, several times I was assigned to do some job involving low resolution images. Such as **icon making, favicon making** etc. These files have very low resolution like **16*16 px, 32*32px** or maybe upto 100px.

I used **Photoshop and Illustrator** for creating such graphics. It looks fine and perfect in high resolution, but when I try to decrease the size to required low resoution, the images have noticeable defects in clarity. I was surprised to see low resolution images in other websites with better clarity and wondering, **How is that possible?** Hope stack will solve my problem.

Comment: Also possible dupes:  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5269/how-to-resize-icon-sets-in-photoshop and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6216/need-advice-on-reducing-icon-size-without-loss-in-detail.

Comment: @e100 You had a comment here and it disappeared when I hit 'close'.  I'm not sure if that was something the system did, but just fyi I didn't delete your comment (unless the close action did).  Other possible dupe e100 linked was http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6386/tools-or-methods-for-optimizing-favicon-appearance

Answer (score 2):

If you need 16X16 icon then you should start design in 16X16 canvas. Resizing from a larger image is always going effect the clarity and crispness no matter what you try and tbh its not the right way to do.

If you need series of icons 16/32/64/128 etc. Then all need to be designed in its original size. No easy!