# How perfectly scale and produce different sizes of icon without losing the quality in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, resize, mobile

I already have sketch icon converted in svg, eps and ai files. And I wanted to produce different specific sizes for mobile app design. How would I properly scale an Icon?

Comment: This is very similar to your other question [How to know if your icon is sharp when user test on phone](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115888/how-to-know-if-your-icon-is-sharp-when-user-test-on-phone). Please don't add questions twice. Instead edit your original question if you wish to add details. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize icon sets in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5269/how-to-resize-icon-sets-in-photoshop)

Answer (score 0):

You simply click on File --> Export --> Export for Screens

[image]

And then on the pop-up window options select the iOS or Android tab/pill. This will automatically generate the needed sizes for both, iOS & Android systems. Then you simply need to save it and that's it!

[image]